# Empty grid column on the right side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I am trying to write the code for a formular. The formular has a validation. I want to show an icon on the right side of the input element when the input is wrong.

This code works but I have understand that Bootstrap needs always 12 columns per row.

```css
<div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Hello</label>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" />
                          <span>icon</span>
                      </div>
                       <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
                  </div>
```

Is there another way more elegant to write this? I read that it is better using offsets than empty divs but how can I use an offset on the right side?

Comment: are you talking about right offset in bootstrap columns ?

Comment: Yes, I think, it is duplicate.